# Python encoding key, minus one character if too long

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

Here is my code so far:

```
def code_block(text, key):
    itext = int(text)
    rkey = int(key)
    res= itext + rkey
    def last():
        return res[-1:]
    if res>=11111111:
        last()
    return res
```

Here is the task I've been set:

> Now we need a function to take a block of code and a key as input, where both are assumed to be 8 digits long, and encrypts each digit of the number with the corresponding digit of the key:
>
> ```
> >>> code_block('12341234','12121212')
> '24462446'
>
> >>> code_block('66554433','44556677')
> '00000000'
> ```

Where am I going wrong? Could you point me in the right direction and indicate me how I was wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with `last()`? You are just discarding the result. Your code just errors out at the moment too, because `res` is an integer, not a string (`TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`).

Comment: And your quotes are not valid Python quotes; did something 'autocorrect' those for you or did you type those by hand?

Comment: With last()
If the code is more than 8 characters long then it shoudl remove the last character.

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code: `33` + `77` is supposed to be `00`; your sum will give it `10` instead, and you are never turning things back into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way. Treat this character by character:

```
def code_block(text, key):
    res = [str(int(c) + int(k))[-1:] for c, k in zip(text, key)]
    return ''.join(res)
```

which gives me:

```
>>> code_block('12341234','12121212')
'24462446'
>>> code_block('66554433','44556677')
'00000000'
```

The code sums *each* and *every* character separately, turning it back into a string and only using the last character of the result; 9 + 9 is 18, but the result would be `'8'`.

Your code would sum the whole numbers, but that would result in:

```
>>> 66554433 + 44556677
111111110
```

which is not the correct result. Neither did you ever turn your sum back into a string again, so your code, attempting to treat the sum result as a string by slicing it, gave an exception:

```
>>> code_block('12341234', '12121212')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in code_block
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in last
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```